# How to get date of the month 15 and 30

Tags: php, date

I trying get something like this

```
16 Jul 2014, 12:00 am - 31 Jul 2014, 11:59 pm
```

How do I achieve it, I know I can use the strtotime feature with $date, but how do I get the half of a month such as 1-15 , 16-31 or maybe 16-30 (depend on some months)

```
$newDate = strtotime('+15 days',$date)
```

**Thanks for helping!!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be done like so:

```
<?php
    $a_date = "2014-7-24"; // calculate from given date (month does count for total days)
    $last_day = date("t", strtotime($a_date)); // 31
    $median = floor($last_day * .5); // 15

    echo "1-" . $median; // 1-15
    echo $median + 1 . "-" . $last_day; // 16-31
?>
```

### Edit

Added function:

```
function split_date($date) {
    $last_day = date("t", strtotime($date));
    $median = floor($last_day * .5);
    return array("last_day" => $last_day, "median" => $median);
}
```

Return an array: `Array ( [last_day] => 31 [median] => 15 )`